# Graphing a path using quaternions as the coordinate space?

Tags: graphing-functions, coordinate-systems, quaternions, kinematics

I'm trying to write an animation sequence for a video game engine that uses quaternions. I've never worked with quaternions before and even though I've spent hours trying to get my head around them, I'm still struggling to apply them to my problem.

Basically, I need to be able to send objects on a path that would be easy to graph in cartesian space but I have to do it with a dual quaternion system. For simplicity's sake, let's just say I have a cylinder with a "nose" end and a "tail" end I need to animate it following a parabolic path to simulate being thrown at a target on the ground. I managed to make it go in a straight line from resting on the ground at the origin, on a path towards the target. However I can neither tell it the coordinate of the target to make it stop when it gets there, nor can I arc its path upwards to simulate flying through the air.

[python code for quaternion stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eh4b.png)

The linked image shows the portion of my code that's incrementing the quaternion coordinates to make the cylinder move. It's Python code but it shouldn't really matter because all that's happening there is basic math. I'm not changing quaternion 2 in a mirrored way to changes to quaternion 1 because I'm trying to translate as well as rotate my cylinder, and I don't want it staying on the same sphere. So the changes to q1 are all commented out. When q2_x is incremented and nothing else is changed, then the cylinder moves in a straight line towards the target. When I added the `q2_y = -(q2_x * q2_x) + (.005*q2_x)` bit, I expected it would move in a parabolic shape but instead it starts to move in a weird screw-shape briefly, before gliding off into the void on a straight path. I was also really confused when I noticed that the amount that I increment q2_x (eg. -=1 versus -=.005) results in a different path but not a significantly different speed of motion. What am I misunderstanding here?

So, to summarize, my question is: how can I model simple motion along a pre-set path in 3 dimensions using quaternions as the coordinates?

Comment: I think you are confused about the role of quaternions in 3D. They are used to model rigid motion about a center of mass of an object. The motion of the object via its center of mass is another thing which is idependant of its orientation. The Wikipedia article [Quaternions and spatial rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) may help yousort this out.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should have clarified the sources I've tried to use to understand this problem. I've read the Wikipedia article on quaternions, as well as checking out the tutorials at https://eater.net/quaternions, https://www.ashwinnarayan.com/post/how-to-integrate-quaternions/, and this dissertation which seems to suggest quaternions are practical for combining rotational and translational rigid-body transformations: https://commons.erau.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1154&context=edt (among other reading materials and textbooks)

Comment: You wrote "I've never worked with quaternions before" and this is a big part of your problem. I don't see how quaternions can combine rotation **and** translation or why you would want to do that.

Comment: For dual-quaternions understanding and implementation take a look at this fabulous articles: http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg2012/short/a29-full.pdf and https://xbdev.net/misc_demos/demos/dual_quaternions_beyond/paper.pdf

Comment: I finally read the Wikipedia article [Dual quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion) and in particular the section "Dual quaternions and 4×4 homogeneous transforms" which splits a dual quaternion into a rotational part and a displacement part and gives a $4\times 4$ matrix representation. In your question you should  mention explicitly which equations or formulas you are trying to implement. They could be wrong.